Access OTG files in Android 12 and above
I want to access any OTG (USB) device plugged in and read the files. I'm building a File Explorer application which can be installed as an OS Application. I want to know how to read/write files from and to the USB OTG device in Kotlin on Android 12 and above.
I have seen and tried solutions where the user will select the folder to allow permission to the USB device, but is it possible to read/write from the USB device without this as the app will be installed as a system app with all permissions.
